# How to change default p:dataTable emptyMessage message

Tags: jsf, internationalization, primefaces, datatable, message

I am using PrimeFaces' dataTable. I get "No records found." when table has no element. I want to change this message to something like "No result" and make this message i18n type.

I don't want to use

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="idTable" 
    ...
    emptyMessage="#{messages['general.message.EmptyList']}"
>
```

for every table.

How can I change p:dataTable default `emptyMessage` message?

Comment: I suggest adding issue to PrimeFaces team. Honestly I think it is time (for tool with that level of maturity) to make properties file with all default messages they are using, so it can be overridden like those default JSF validation messages. Not just for datatable, but for all components.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the PrimeFaces 3.5 `DataTable` source code:

```
210    public java.lang.String getEmptyMessage() {
211        return (java.lang.String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.emptyMessage, "No records found.");
212    }
```

So, it's hard coded and there's no way to change it in a single place other way than hacking the PrimeFaces source or creating a [tagfile (not composite!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) `<my:dataTable>` which wraps the `<p:dataTable>` with the desired message set.

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <p:dataTable id="#{id}" value="#{value}" var="item" 
        emptyMessage="#{messages['general.message.EmptyList']}">
        <ui:insert />
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

```
<my:dataTable id="foo" value="#{bean.items}">
    <p:column>#{item.foo}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{item.bar}</p:column>
</my:dataTable>
```

If you actually don't want to **change** the message, but merely want to **hide** it altogether, then you could also opt for a pure CSS solution:

```css
.ui-datatable-empty-message {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is it there any reason for this to be hardcoded still in version 6?

Answer (score -1):

write emptyMessage="" inside the datatable 
Ej:

```
<p:dataTable var="hola"
    value="#{logica.hola}"
    emptyMessage="text you want to appear" >
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Just plain code isn't a complete answer. Please explain yourself as well, that's a generell rule. But furthermore you didn't provide any new information, so your answer is redundant and doesn't improve the provided information here.

Comment: sorry. I wanted to say that you write the text you want to appear between the quotes ""