# p:datatable initial message

Tags: primefaces

I have a datatable and before any search has been done, the inital message is "no records found" where as I want the initial message to be "No search criteria has been provided".

I used the emptyMessage to change it however this also changes it if no records are returned. E.g. a search returns 0 results and the message returned is "No search criteria has provided". Which is incorrect.

Is it possible to change the initial message only?

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855952/how-to-change-default-pdatatable-emptymessage-message). Is it what you need?

Comment: I don't that was the same issue. I managed to use "#{TableData eq null ? ' ': text.noRecordsFound}"

Comment: @Mken: please create an answer... with code and an explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default p:dataTable emptyMessage message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855952/how-to-change-default-pdatatable-emptymessage-message)